# Converting Nodejs DynamoDB query to AWS CLI command

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I studied dynamoDB in a different way. I wanted a AWS CLI version but the keywords and terms to search is very difficult.

So I decided to make a javascript version.

Can anyone convert this nodejs dynamodb querys to AWS CLI?

Create Table

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const region = "us-west-2";

AWS.config.update({
  region
});
AWS.config.dynamodb = {
    endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('http://localhost:8005'),
    region
}

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB() //low-level client

const tableName = "Services";

const params = {
    TableName : tableName,
    KeySchema: [       
        { AttributeName: "pk", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "sk", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [       
        { AttributeName: "pk", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "sk", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {       
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Insert 2 rows:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const region = "us-west-2";

AWS.config.update({
  region
});
AWS.config.dynamodb = {
    endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('http://localhost:8005'),
    region
}
const ddbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB() 

const params = {
  RequestItems: {
    "Services": [
        {
          PutRequest: {
            Item: {
              "pk": { S:"1"},
              "sk": { S:"1"},
              "Service": {S:"Express"},
              "Range1": {N:"0000000"},
              "Range2": {N:"2000000"},
              "Counters": {N:"0"},
              "TriggerUpdate": {N:"1"}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          PutRequest: {
            Item: {
              "pk": { S:"2"},
              "sk": { S:"2"},
              "Service": {S:"Saver"},
              "Range1": {N:"2000001"},
              "Range2": {N:"3999999"},
              "Counters": {N:"0"},
              "TriggerUpdate": {N:"1"}
            }
          }
        }
    ]
  }
};
  

ddbClient.batchWriteItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to write data: ", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("PutItem succeeded");
    }
});
```

Update a specific item. I couldn't search what Im looking for, its supposed to increment the Counters column. Can anyone also teach me how to do that?

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const region = "us-west-2";

AWS.config.update({
  region
});
AWS.config.dynamodb = {
    endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('http://localhost:8005'),
    region
}

// const ddbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB()
const ddbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

const params = {
    TableName: "Services",
    Key: {
        pk: "1",
        sk: "1"
    },
    UpdateExpression: "add Counters :value",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":val": "1"
    },
    ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'TOTAL',
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
};
return ddbClient.update(params).promise();
```

Example result would be:
`aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://create-table.json --endpoint=http://localhost:8003`

I assure you this codes works. I can see it in my NoSQL Workbench DynamoDB Offline.

Answer (score 1):

To increment a counter via update item, you can use the following update expression (via CLI per your request):

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name Services \
    --key '{"pk":{"S":"1"}, "sk":{"S":"1"}}' \
    --update-expression "SET Price = Price + 1" \
    --return-values ALL_NEW
```

For your other JS samples, could you share what you attempted to do via CLI and what error you got?

Comment: I had no error. Only for the update it doesnt `add Counters :value`

Comment: yea that update-item, doesnt work

Comment: this is the error when i run the update-item `Error parsing parameter '--key': Invalid JSON: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 32 (char 31)
JSON received: {"pk":{"S":"1"}, "sk":{"S":"1"}` this data exist in the database

Comment: I believe I was missing a curly brace, updated my answer.

Comment: `An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "1", near: "+ 1"`